# I want to show that full wave rectification equation is correct by Proteus

Tags: transformer

I want to verify the full wave rectification equation using Proteus, but I get wrong voltage values. Please if any body knows how to do it, tell me.

[image]

Comment: What kind of instrument is the voltmeter on the right? Is it measuring dc, peak, something else? Why are there junction dots in some places in your wiring? Are you sure you don't have a missed connection somewhere?

Comment: Which is   Vrms = 2Vp/pi

Comment: All the volt metmeters are dc volt meter available in proteous app. The blue dot id the center of the board.

Comment: Yes it measures dc. It is sure because the left one shows 229 v.

Comment: All connections are good. If i placed a bulb instered of load resistor v= 2.8. That means connections are ok

Comment: I deleted all unnessesory junction dots. But out put is still -0.02

Comment: When i placed the capacitor volt meter shows v= Vpeak which is correct

Comment: I checked connections by moving blocks here and there, ok.

Comment: I can't up load my proteous project file, so some one can ckeck, instered of image.

Comment: Can it be my proteous app fake?

Comment: No, your app is fine, simply in proteous the DC voltmeter measures only "pure" DC voltage. And will not show you the average voltage as any modern voltmeter do. Add smoothing capacitor across the load.

Comment: If i add the capacitor meter gives the peak voltage. What i want is Vrms without smoothing.

Comment: Does any body know what voltmeter I should use in proteus to get the Vrms reading please?